# How to write Parallel ForEach in Viola-Jones

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing, parallel.foreach, viola-jones

I want to speed up Viola-Jones by extracting detected face parallel, I use this code but there is an error in face argument within For Each statement, Can you tell me how to fix this error Please?
the error is

> (Error    2   The type arguments for method `System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach<TSource>(System.Collections.Concurrent.OrderablePartitioner<TSource>, System.Action<TSource,System.Threading.Tasks.ParallelLoopState,long>)` cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.
>   D:\Hadeel\00 thesis\Face recognition\C #\Backup\Viola and Jones Results
>   2 - Copy\Viola and Jones Results 2\Form1.cs 356 25
>   Viola and Jones Results 2)

```
else if (chcParallel.Checked == true)
{//Rectangle face=new Rectangle();
    Parallel.ForEach(  face, faceObjects =>
    {
        graphicRect.DrawRectangle(p, face);
        face.Inflate(-10, -10);// resize face for crop face without background

        Crop crop = new Crop(face);

        Bitmap newimage = crop.Apply(image);

        // ResizeBicubic resixe = new ResizeBicubic(460, 480);
        //newimage = resixe.Apply(newimage);
        //pictureBox2.Image = (newimage); 
        if (chcSkin.Checked == false)
        {
            facearray[i] = newimage;
            pictureBox2.Image = facearray[i];
            i = i + 1;
        }
        else if (chcSkin.Checked == true)
        {
            f1 = 0; f2 = 0; f3 = 0;
            Bitmap imagess = new Bitmap(newimage);
            for (int x = 0; x < imagess.Width - 1; x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < imagess.Height - 1; y++)
                {
                    Color pixelColor = imagess.GetPixel(x, y);
                    int r = pixelColor.R;
                    int g = pixelColor.G;
                    int b = pixelColor.B;
                    //        int f1 = 0;
                    //        int f2 = 0;
                    //        int f3 = 0;
                    int differenceMinMax = Math.Max(r, Math.Max(g, b)) - Math.Min(r, Math.Min(g, b));

                    if (r > 95 & g > 40 & b > 20 & differenceMinMax > 15 & r > g & r > b)
                    {
                        f1 = f1 + 1;// image.SetPixel(x, y, Color.White);
                    }
                    else if (r > 220 & g > 210 & b > 170)
                    {
                        f2 = f2 + 1;// imagess.SetPixel(x, y, Color.White);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        f3 = f3 + 1;// imagess.SetPixel(x, y, Color.White);
                    }
                }
            }
            if ((f1 > f2) && (f1 > f3))
            {
                facearray[i] = newimage;
                pictureBox2.Image = facearray[i];
                i = i + 1;
            }
        }
        //else
        //{ }
    });

    graphicRect.Dispose();
    pictureBox1.Image = image;
}//end if Parallel True
```

Comment: what types are `face` and `faceObjects` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell for sure, but are you trying to mark the `face` object as a lambda parameter? Then you need to switch parameters:

```
// for each of faceObject do
Parallel.ForEach(faceObjects, face =>
{
    // your code here
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , yes i did it , but any way it is not work , parallel is not possible as i was think .

Comment: I mean, I could not make parallel processing in viola jones code , i just want to make it faster for real time face detection, but can not do it